# Diagonal conic with no points mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms

What is the smallest prime $p$ for which there exists a quadratic form

$$Q=aX^2+bY^2+cZ^2 \quad (a,b,c \in \mathbf F_p  \setminus \{0\} )$$

such that the conic $\{Q=0\}$ has no points in $\mathbf P^2(\mathbf F_p)$?

(This may well be judged "not research-level". For what it's worth, I searched online and asked a couple of colleagues, but without success.)

Comment: Every conic over a finite field has a rational point. This is Corollary 2 in Serre's "A Course in Arithmetic". The proof is by applying Chevalley-Warning to the defining equation.

Comment: There is even an easy counting argument: since the functions $ax^2$ and $c-by^2$ both assume $(p+1)/2$ values when evaluated on the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$, there must be a value in common to them, which yields your solution to $ax^2+by^2=c$.

Comment: You can also prove this using Wedderburn's theorem (which I believe predates Chevalley-Warning).  Every conic without points is the Severi-Brauer variety of a quaternion algebra.  Wedderburn proved that all division algebras over finite fields are just finite fields.